# How to check multiple conditions in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Ufg.png)I have a scenario where I have to check two conditions and if both are true then execute set of activities in ADF.

I tried if condition activity inside a if condition but ADF is not allowing it.

so basically my design is two lookups to read data and then if condition to check condition 1, if that is true then go inside again two lookups to read data and if condition to check condition 2. But it is not working.

is there any other work around for this?

I tried AND condition inside IF condition activity but it is not working. Please suggest.

Comment: I Tried like this also but it is giving error -- @and
    (greater(activity('MAX_DATE_FROM_ASQL').output.firstRow.MAX_DATE_ASQL,activity('MAX_DATE_FROM_HIVE').output.firstRow.MAX_DATE_HIVE)),
    (greater(activity('CURRENT_TIME').output.firstRow.CURRENT_TIME,activity('QLIK_MAX_DATE').output.firstRow.qlik_date_time_stamp))

Comment: Can you please provide the error message?

Comment: 'String' does not match with the field: 'expression'

Comment: Hi @HariCh, could you please provide pipeline image

Comment: @BhanunagasaiVamsi Added to original Question. Sorry if it bit odd.

Comment: Hey, DId you try executing the pipeline? and get this failure message because this is a warning message in ADF

Comment: @Nandan It is bit weird. The pipeline was not triggered earlier and giving some issue. But now it is started executing and seems fine. I will have to test my scenarios but hope it works. But the condition I used is make sense , right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we cannot use IF within IF activity, we can leverage multiple conditions within an IF activity via expressions which includes if,and ,or etc functions.

The below JSON pipeline is somewhat an example :

```
{
    "name": "pipeline7",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "If Condition1",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@and(greater(pipeline().parameters.Test2, pipeline().parameters.Test1),greater(pipeline().parameters.Test4, pipeline().parameters.Test3))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "ifFalseActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Wait2",
                            "type": "Wait",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "waitTimeInSeconds": 1
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Wait1",
                            "type": "Wait",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "waitTimeInSeconds": 1
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "Test1": {
                "type": "int",
                "defaultValue": 1
            },
            "Test2": {
                "type": "int",
                "defaultValue": 2
            },
            "Test3": {
                "type": "int",
                "defaultValue": 3
            },
            "Test4": {
                "type": "int",
                "defaultValue": 4
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Your approach is correct in case if you dont want to create another pipeline and use execute activity within the IF activity for another comparision